# Discord.py как сделать кнопки рядом друг с другом?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Мне нужно, чтобы мои кнопки в дискорде были рядом друг с другом, а не так, чтобы одна была под другой. Как это сделать?
Фрагмент кода:

```
await ctx.send(
        embed=discord.Embed(title='123',
                            description='456',
                            colour=discord.Color.green()),
        components=[
            Button(style=ButtonStyle.grey, label='text1'),
            Button(style=ButtonStyle.grey, label='text2')
        ]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы кнопки находились на одной линии, поместите их во вложенный список.

Например:

```
await ctx.send(
    embed=discord.Embed(title='123',
                        description='456',
                        colour=discord.Color.green()),
    components=[
        #первая линия
        [Button(style=ButtonStyle.grey, label='к1 л1'),
         Button(style=ButtonStyle.grey, label='к2 л1')],
        #вторая линия
        [Button(style=ButtonStyle.grey, label='к1 л2'),
         Button(style=ButtonStyle.grey, label='к2 л2')]
    ]
)
```